# Slackware /etc/slackpkg/mirrors

Tags: slackware

Hello I am new in Linux Slackware and I have problem when I tapping:

slackpkg search gcc

after that got this one:

You do not have any mirror selected in /etc/slackpkg/mirrors
Please edit that file and uncomment ONE mirror.  Slackpkg
only works with ONE mirror selected.

I am from Israel, How can solve this problem thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well, did you consider doing what the message says?

*Please edit that file (/etc/slackpkg/mirrors) and uncomment ONE mirror.*

That's the solution. Use an editor like `nano` or `vi` and choose a single mirror from the list, possibly one that is geographically close to you for greater transfer speed. Remove the leading hash sign (`#`) on that line, save the file and re-run your command.

Answer (score 0):

Michael. There is a tool in Slackware that works like a package manager. It can help you a lot with installations of packages.
The tool name is SBotools and you can find and read more about here: https://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/system/sbotools/

To install, just read the how to of slackbuilds and enjoy it :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. The question was about slackpkg, not slackbuilds.